# Visual Studio code multiple .cpp project recompile changed files only

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

What is the best way to make sure in multi files project, Vscode runs MSYS2 compiler only for changed files and does linking at the end?

All MS tutorials are like

> compiler_path file1.c file2.c file3.c filen.c -Iinc_path1 -o output.exe

And it takes ages if project has 50+ files in the project

How to shorted this down to bare minimum?

Comment: Using a proper build system, such as `make` will do that automatically for you

Comment: Or use CMake and the CMake Tools Extension of VSCode: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)